What is this object that is transported onboard an ambulance aircraft in Sweden?
While watching the news on 7 November, I saw this picture:

The news clip (playhead position 18:29) is talking about an ambulance or organ-transportation aircraft in Sweden, which tail-id is SE-RVA.
What is this coffin-shaped object with monitors and windows, that is transported in the picture and what is its purpose?
It seems the object is transferred from the aircraft to an ambulance using the metal support with wheels that can be seen to the left in the picture.

This question is not about aviation and is rather about a specific piece of cargo. Maybe go to Medical Sciences Stack Exchange.

Not an aviation question. It would have been just as meaningful to ask about the metal box being placed on an ambulance. And just as off topic.

I don’t agree that this is off topic since this is probably an object especially designed for air transport (even though I have no idea what it is).

@mins The key is that it meets RTCA DO-160.

It's an incubator for newborn infants designed for air transport. In particular, it's an International Biomedical NxtGen.

(Manufacturer's promotional photo)
